# Class Diagram in Mongodb

Tags: mongodb, uml, nosql

I want to make the UML for my application (i did the inverse, starting by the application because i am a beginner in internet stuff), so my question is:

i've `Produit` which i denormalized, so, it will be copied two times:

- if it is a product uploaded, then it will have methods like `supprimer` (`delete`),
- if it is added to cart, then i will not have the `supprimer` (`delete`) method, but have `enlever_du_panier` (`reomve_from_cart`).
- So how can i show in UML that this method goes only for uploaded product and not from added_to_cart, so i make two classes with the same attributes but different methods?
- If i have the document such as **sub-document**; for example, the `client` is splited to `city` , and `city` doesent play a big role in the system, but only did that to make the document scanning **fast**, would i represent it in the system **AS IT IS SPLITTED?**

[image]

Comment: what does this have to do with MongoDB?

Comment: mongodb is not relational, so i dont know how to make class diagram when it is a json

Comment: MongoDB can be relational, just not server-side...the joins are client side...why don't you put those in instead of the server side joins? UML applies mostly to MongoDB the same as it does to RDBMS as lot

Comment: @Sammaye so how about the denormalized? how can i represent it? they share the same attributes but differs in methods

Comment: Since this is a class diagram: Are they separate classes?

Comment: @Sammaye , no, the whole is one document with sub-documents, so i tried to modelise it as 'old' way

Comment: Hmm then it comes down to preference really. I would show it has a class entity within the class with the root document being a container for the list of subclasses

Comment: sorry but i dont get the idea, never seen an example like that, i was just trying some 'basic' class diagram, and they were so simple to ne have nested?

Comment: Hmm it does appear as though class diagrams actually have a crude method of nesting: http://www.sparxsystems.com/resources/uml2_tutorial/uml2_classdiagram.html , does that answer your question?

Comment: ah! thank you! so this is new! because in the document i got (even uml2) there was no nesting diagrams, this is why i used aggregation

Comment: @Sammaye i'll go with that solution, the last thing: the problem is if i use the nested documents, then i duplicated the `product`, the `cart` which has methods like `remove_from_cart` and the duplicated is `upload product` which will have the method `remove`, do i use a normal classes? what if i use inheritance since they only differ in methods?

Comment: Inheritance would be better here, one method of UML nesting assumes that the child is nested in the parent as such, technically should inherit all abilities of its parent

Comment: @Sammaye so i will draw two same classes that have no attributes that inherit from product class, and those two classes have only methods? can you advice me with a simple sketch?