# Nesting VS Aggregation?

Tags: mongodb, uml

What is the best way to represent [MongoDB](http://www.10gen.com/presentations/webinar-general-technical-overview-mongodb-dev-teams) documents; i put the `Product` as a sub-document of the `Client`.

[First, i've put them as Aggregation; if the `Client` is broken, the `Product` is broken too.
Do i use that model, or do i switch to Nesting.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17177067/class-diagram-in-mongodb)

Example of nested diagram:

[image: Nesting]

[image]

Comment: Please include actual examples with data and a list of your use cases for accessing and writing your data. Your model should be chosen to accommodate your use cases. See the following as well for a good walk through on data modelling in MongoDB: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/data-modeling/

Comment: @JamesWahlin just updated it

Comment: @AbdelouahabPp, there is still no actual document to show what you mean.

Comment: @Derick it is in the link added

Comment: Put the question here, not in some other place! The information at that link might go away at any moment making this Q & A useless.

Comment: @Derick i updated it, as you can see i have added lot of classes, and tried to use the inheritance and aggregation together

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**From programming perspective (e.g. Java):**

Reference: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/nested.html

Nested classes are divided into two categories: static and non-static. Nested classes that are declared static are simply called static nested classes. Non-static nested classes are called inner classes.

```
class OuterClass {
    ...
    static class StaticNestedClass {
        ...
    }
    
    class InnerClass {
        ...
    }
    InnerClass innerObject = new InnerClass();
}
```

OuterClass.StaticNestedClass nestedObject = new OuterClass.StaticNestedClass();

**From UML perspective:**

1. Class generalize from Namespace

   Class--|>EncapsulatedClassifier--|>StructuredClassifier--|>Classifier--|>Namespace
2. Namespace has "member" and "ownedMember".

   /member : NamedElement [0..*]

   /ownedMember : NamedElement [0..*]

   the "member" represents "StaticNestedClass + InnerClass";the "ownedMember" represents "InnerClass" only

**General suggestions:**

1. I wouldn't use "nesting" connector; It will cause confusion between "StaticNestedClass" and "InnerClass".
2. I wouldn't use "aggregation" connector (white diamond); because it was introduced by legacy reason;
3. Always use "Association" and "Composition".

**How to do diagramming?**

1. If you want to model an element of "StaticNestedClass", give it "OuterClass::StaticNestedClass" as class name. No connectors involved.
2. If you want to model "InnerClass" (In UML Specification, it is called "nestedClassifier"),
   (1) Create two class elements on the diagram, give names "OuterClass" and "OuterClass::InnerClass" respectively.
   (2) Draw an "Composition" connector from "OuterClass" to "OuterClass::InnerClass".

**Association or Composition**

It is really depends on your requirement.

Most people likes to describe "Composition" from "destroy" process; The "whole" destroyed, then the "parts" got destroyed as well.

However, it is always valid to describe from "construct" process; In the process you "new the whole", you "newed the parts".
It is good practice to make "construct" and "destroy" them consistent.

E.g. Car and Wheel;

If someone wrote following crazy code, WOW..

```
class Car{
public: 
    Wheel* w1;
    Wheel* w2;
    Car(Wheel* w1_, Wheel* w2_)
    {
        w1 = w1_;
        w2 = w2_;
    }
    ~Car()
    {
        delete w1;
        delete w2;
    }
}

Wheel* l1 = new Wheel();
Wheel* l2 = new Wheel();
Car* myCar = new Car(l1, l2);
delete myCar;
l1->Operation1();    //Crash!
```

So this is not a real "Composition" because the construct and destroy is not consistent.
If you remove the "delete w1;delete w2" from destructor, then the relationship between Car and Wheel is "**Association**".

The Composition version of code will be like this:

```
class Car{
public: 
    Wheel* w1;
    Wheel* w2;
    Car()
    {
        w1 = new Wheel();
        w2 = new Wheel();
    }
    ~Car()
    {
        delete w1;
        delete w2;
    }
}
```

Comment: ah thank you! i did it using `composition` so it seems more correct